# ASP.net core Odata Remove "@odata.context" and "value" from response

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi

Is there any way to remove the odata context and value from the Response
so its just my object as a response?

```
"@odata.context": "https://localhost/api/$metadata#ComplexObject",
    "value": [
       {
          "name": "SomeName"
       }
```

so the return object is like this:

```
{
   "name": "SomeName"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could write a custom middleware as described in the docs?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0

I don't know at which position you must inject the new middleware but you can inject it anywhere in the request pipeline